# How to limit CPU resources / Shockwave Flash

Tags: flash, adobe, limit, cpu-usage, shockwave

Can I set a maximum percentage of CPU resources a specific program or process can use? I want to use the executable name instead of its pid, because I would like certain executables to always run with constrained resources.

The reason I ask for that is that I am bored of the way Shockwave Flash behaves. It is not possible that to draw a few stupid things in my browser it takes 50%, 80%, 99% of my dual core CPU!

Thank you,

Pietro

MacBook Pro 2009 - 
MacOS X 10.6.4 - 
Chrome 6.0 - 
Firefox

P.S.: Now, when my fan starts running I now the reason and I know how to temporarily fix it: I kill Shockwave Flash and everything is back as normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to ask your question in SuperUser. It sounds more like a hardware/software issue than actually a programming issue. You blame Shockwave Flash and admittedly some badly designed apps will bring your CPU down but not all apps.

I also have a Macbook Pro, older & slower than yours actually. The fans never bother me although I develop Flash apps! If your diagnostic was accurate, I don't think I'll be able to work at all!

Comment: I will look on SuperUser (I did not know about it). Thank you.